# How to Queuing Items to be added into React Native Context's State

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-hooks

I'm trying to show logs like `console.log` in my app UI using React Native Context. I have this codes in the context:

```
...
const [logs, setLogs] = useState<string[]>([]);
const addToConsoleLogs = (log: string) => {
  setLogs([...logs, log]);
};
...
```

and in the screen when I call that function before and after a fetch:

```
...
doFetch = () => {
  addToConsoleLogs('Start..');
  await fetch(...);
  addToConsoleLogs('Done.');
}
...
```

is not working as expected, because this part >> `setLogs([...logs, log]);`, the previous logs state value seems not actual in the second call because I think those calls are in the same thread and they're asynchronous. Too bad we can't put `await` in front of the `setLogs()`. What is the best way to mimic `console.log` in React Native Hooks mechanism?

Answer (score 0):

We can use state callback: `setLogs(logs => [...logs, log])` and all callings are waiting the callback.